# Creating chains that loop on themselves

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

I want to have a number that breaks into 2 other numbers and checks for end conditions, breaking off each number until the conditions are met.

I came up with the following example to try to figure it out. Take a number, and break it into 2 more numbers: one is the original number multiplied by 2 and the other number is the original number divided by 3 without a remainder (//). This continues until a number is either greater than 100, equal to 6, or a square.

I want to record every chain that is made to be returned and printed out at the end. I can only do this by checking the second number in a chain currently and am not clever enough to figure out how to check both numbers. I want a new chain to be created every time the number is broken into 2 new numbers.

Currently, here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np

def check_conditions(number):
    if number > 100:
        return False
    if number == 6:
        return False
    if np.sqrt(number) % 1 == 0:
        return False
    return True

def find_decay(number):
    '''
    Rule: Number is broken into two chains. First chain is 
    mulitplied by 2. Seconds chain is // 3. Same thing happens
    to both chains unless end condition is met:
    1. number is greater than 100
    2. number is equal to 6
    3. number is a perfect square
    '''
    master_chain = []
    while check_conditions(number):
        new_chain1 = [number * 2]
        master_chain.append(new_chain1)
        new_chain2 = [number // 3]
        master_chain.append(new_chain2)
        number = new_chain2[-1]
    return master_chain

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print find_decay(int(raw_input('Number: ')))
```

Does anyone have any ideas of ways to check conditions in a while loop for 2 separate numbers like?

Comment: So you want to continuously apply the `find_decay` function until both numbers meet your conditions?

Comment: These aren't going to be "chains" as such; you're going to generate a tree, since you branch into two on every step.

Comment: You are producing a *tree* of numbers; each number branching off into two directions. You can still add all the numbers into a list of course. You need to decide if you are going to follow one branch all the way down (depth first) or if you are scan the tree level by level (breath first).

Comment: Depth-first, you will end up with a very boring sequence: either you always end up at `1` or `6` (going down the `//3` branch) or always `> 100` (going down the other).

Comment: I think it would be better to go with depth first. And yeah, generating a tree is a better name for it than a chain.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem typically lends itself to [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) and/or [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). However, the rate at which you're spawning new work is quite high compared to the rate at which you're going to satisfy the conditions. (ie while it won't take too many operations to exceed 100 for one product of each value, but low chances of finding a perfect square or exactly 6 on either fork)

Therefore, you'll want to set a max recursion depth for your implementation else you'll come up against the interpreter's limit (`sys.getrecursionlimit()`) and fail ugly.

I've provided a simple example of how you might do it below, recursively building a tree.

This is not particularly efficient though, and if you are interested in very long 'chains' then you may need to consider addressing this another way.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,number,parent):
        self._parent = parent
        self._number = number
        self._satisfied = number > 100 or number == 6 or np.sqrt(number) % 1 == 0
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._depth = parent.depth + 1 if parent != None else 1

    @property
    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number

    @property
    def satisfied(self):
        return self._satisfied

    @property
    def depth(self):
        return self._depth

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self._left

    @left.setter
    def left(self,value):
        self._left = value

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self._right

    @right.setter
    def right(self,value):
        self._right = value

def print_all_chains(node,chain=[]):
    if node.left is None:
        chain.append(node.number)
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(node.satisfied, chain)
    else:
        print_all_chains(node.left, chain[:] + [node.number])
        print_all_chains(node.right, chain[:] + [node.number])

def build_tree(node, maxDepth):
    if not node.satisfied and node.depth<maxDepth:
        node.left = Node(node.number*2, node)
        build_tree(node.left,maxDepth)
        node.right = Node(node.number//3, node)
        build_tree(node.right,maxDepth)

def find_decay(number):
    root = Node(number,None)
    build_tree(root,maxDepth=10)
    print_all_chains(root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_decay(int(raw_input('Number: ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `Node` class, this can give you an idea of the tree structure. This traverses the tree in level-order (which guarantees to find the shortest chain):

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np

def check_conditions(number):
    return number > 100 or number == 6 or np.sqrt(number) % 1 == 0

class Node():
    def __init__(self, value, parent=None):
        self.value, self.parent = value, parent

    def chain(self):
        node = self
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.parent

def find_decay(number):
    agenda = deque([Node(number)])

    while agenda:
        node = agenda.popleft()  # use pop() for depth-first
        num = node.value
        if check_conditions(num):
            return list(node.chain())
        agenda.append(Node(num//3, parent=node))
        agenda.append(Node(num*2, parent=node))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in find_decay(int(raw_input('Number: '))):
        print x,

37: 37 12 4
```